# Definition Words

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

We have been getting a lot of questions lately asking us to define terms.  One of our more recent ones[what is your definition of the word home](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/29024/what-is-your-definition-of-the-word-home) was sent over to English SE in which a moderator there commented to me that they don't do philosophical breakdown of words.  Should we still suggest those to English SE where they can be put on hold and be re-written? Or do we simply close down the question here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a question does not, in its present form, fit the requirements of the site we're considering migrating to, then we should put it on hold until it can be fixed.  If we migrate something that doesn't fit on the other site, then (a) they'll just close it (bouncing it back to us) and (b) we'll cause frustration for both their users *and* the OP (who's being bounced around).

If people who know the other site's guidelines can leave comments explaining what needs to be changed, that'd be a great way to help the OP get an answer.

Some questions can't be made to fit on any site.  Unfortunately, all we can do is put those on hold.  The question you linked to is one of those -- it's a subjective polling question, not an answerable Stack Exchange question.

A final note: we should only consider migration when the question *doesn't fit here*.  A question that's on-topic here shouldn't be migrated just because it fits better somewhere else.  (This isn't a comment on your question, just a general caution.)

Comment: So in this case we just mark it as on hold? Even if we ask them to define home objectively, it still will need to go to the english site.  So i suppose we wait for that change if it happens

Comment: @ggiaquin right -- in its current form it doesn't work on either site, so put it on hold and wait.  Maybe the OP will make it fit our site and we can reopen, or fit the other site and we can migrate, or do nothing and it stays closed.